# Option value as url in select dropdown

Tags: html

I am using the following as my nav menu in a 320px viewport (iPhone for example)

```
  <select>
     <option value="#">Home</option>
     <option value="#">About</option>
     <option value="#">Products and Services</option>
     <option value="#">Markets</option>
     <option value="#">Case Studies</option>
     <option value="#">Markets</option>
     <option value="#">Partners</option>
     <option value="#">Contact Us</option>
     <option value="#">Careers</option>
     <option value="#">News</option>
  </select>
```

I want to set the value as a link to the corresponding page. How do I go about setting this, I have put the URL in as the value but it does not work. Am I even approaching this correctly?

Comment: Do you only want to use html? Sounds like something easy done with javascript.

Comment: ah ok, using javascript is fine by me? any ideas where to start, my javascript is basic at best at the moment

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, i understand what is happening now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var url = $(this).val();
    window.location = url;
});
```

Add a `change`-event to (every) select element. When it it changed the function is run. The function takes the value from the newly selected option (in this case a url), and sets that url as the new location of the window.

Comment: Thanks so much, works like a charm. so what is happening here is jquery gets the select element, changes its function, grabs the url as the value and then sets  your window location (target page)? is this right?

Comment: Info updated above. I suggest not using just "select", add an id on the select and use "#theId" instead.

Comment: had to wait 5 mins to select an answer, would have clicked then if i could

Answer (score 5):

You can put the URLs to the pages as value attributes for the options. In the example below I used URLs to common websites, but you can use the URLs to the pages in your site.

```
<select id="nav">
     <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
     <option value="http://www.ebay.com">eBay</option>
     <option value="http://www.amazon.com">Amazon</option>
</select>
```

If you want to go to the URL that the user chooses when he changes the value in the dropdown you can do that using JavaScript. First, get the select element [by its ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById). Then, [add an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) which is the function that will execute [when the value is changed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/change). In that function [set the user's browser to go to that URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location).

```
document.getElementById("nav").addEventListener('change', function () {
    window.location = this.value;
}, false);​
```

You can see my example in action in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/LySGk/).

Answer (score 0):

For small displays `select` navigation menu emulated by `<ul><li>` - see twitter bootsrap or analog how it works.