# How can I add a url to a select input's option?

Tags: html, laravel, listbox

Im trying to create a liste box with each of the item send to a different profile
I have my variable $ru who get all the users it's working .
I tryed this but it's not working:

```
 <select  class="chosen form-control" name="User"  style="height:28px" >
    <option selected="selected"> Rechercher </option>
    @foreach($ru as $user)

        <option value="/profile/$user->id ">
            <a href="{{  url('/profile/'.$user->id) }} "> {{$user->name}}  </a>
        </option>

    @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cant add an href like that just add it to the value and use an event listener:
Add the jquery link to you script tag, replace my url and value with yours.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#user').change(function(){
      window.location = this.value;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select  class="chosen form-control" name="User" id="user">
  <option>Select profile</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com"> user name </option>
</select>
```

source : [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429963/option-value-as-url-in-select-dropdown)

Comment: Im not good with javascript I tryed to add 
and I changed my code to what did you write but it's not working can you clarify if I should change something In your code please? or just put it on my view

Answer (score 0):

href Link is not possible in select / option. You can use jQuery to redirect to the profile selected.

Following is the example:

```
<select  class="chosen form-control" name="User"  style="height:28px" >

  <option selected="selected">
    Rechercher
  </option>

  @foreach($ru as $user)
  <option value="{{  url('/profile/'.$user->id) }}">{{$user->name}}
  </option>
  @endforeach

</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[name="User"]').change(function(){

    var profile_url = $('[name="User"]').value();

    // redirect to user profile
    if(profile_url != "")
      window.location.href = profile_url;  

  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It didn't work should I change something in your code please?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <select required class="form-control" id="user"  name="User" onchange="getUser()" required>
                 <option value="All">--All--</option>
                       @foreach($ru as $user)
                 <option value="{{ $user->id }}" {{ (old('user')== $user->id||($user) == $user->id) ? "selected" : "" }}>{{$user->name}}</option>
                      @endforeach
               </select>

//javascript
 function getUser()
    {
        var t=  $('#user').val();
        if(t!= "" ){
            location.href="/profile/"+t;
        }
    }
```